# MySQL IF Statement issue in a Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

So I am trying to create  trigger that will only execute when a specific column within a table  is updated. The table in question is track the column in question is track.track_hits. What I want to do is if that value changes then it inserts a value into a table called play_log. The insert should be the track_id from track and a timestamp.

The code I have done so far is below but it doesn't work, how can it be fixed?

```
CREATE TRIGGER pi_play AFTER UPDATE ON track
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
            if :new.track_hits != :old.track_hits
            then
    INSERT INTO play_log (track_id,access_time)
    VALUES (NEW.track_id, NOW())
            end if;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEW and OLD do not need `:` in front. Also, when creating triggers, you may need to change the delimiter. If you don't change the delimiter, your create trigger statement may be terminated early.

Here's how I would do it:

```
delimiter |

create trigger pi_play after update on track
for each row
begin
  if new.track_hits != old.track_hits then
    insert into play_log(track_id, access_time) values (new.track_id, now());
  end if;
end|

delimiter ;
```

Here's the fiddle showing it in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d99d/1 Notice that I changed the delimiter in the schema window to `|` instead of the default `;`. Since SQL uses JDBC and JDBC doesn't take the command `DELIMITER`, I chose the delimiter.

Comment: in Oracle, you do need the colon (:)